# Looking for a proper multi thread lock

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm looking for certain kind of multi thread lock,
For example,

```
ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
new Thread(()=>
{
    //Do something here, we name it "Task 1"
    mre.Set();
}).Start();
mre.WaitOne();
//Do another thing, we name it "Task 2"
```

This will ensure Task 2 will not be executed until Task 1 is completed.

Now there is another case

```
    //We assume there are two tasks must be completed before the third can be started
int taskCount = 2;
SomeLock lock = new SomeLock(taskCount);
new Thread(()=>
{
    //Do something here, we name it "Task 1"
    lock.Release();
}).Start();
new Thread(()=>
{
    //Do something here, we name it "Task 2"
    lock.Release();
}).Start();
lock.Wait();
//Do another thing, we name it "Task 3"
```

The `lock` is constructed with one parameter indicating the sum of the tasks(in this case, two).

Then `lock.Wait()` should block the program until both threads complete their task and exit.

It's like a reverse version of `Semaphore`.

Comment: A reversed version of Semaphore which `Wait()` will block until all semaphores are released.

Comment: Would [WaitAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.waithandle.waitall) fit your needs?

Comment: You probably need CountdownEvent - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.countdownevent?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: @EvkSolved, `CountdownEvent is exactly what i'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the thread pool and the `Task` library? It contains the method `Task.WaitAll`, which can do what you want.

```
Task task1 = Task.Run(() =>
 {
 // do something
 });

Task task2 = Task.Run(() =>
 {
 // do something else
 });

Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);
```

Comment: Yes, I later found it's a proper approach too.

Comment: Yes, I later found it's a proper approach too.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't directly answering your question, but this is an alternative approach. Try Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx) - NuGet `System.Reactive` and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;` - then you can do this:

```
async Task Main()
{
    var query1 =
        from t1 in Observable.Start(() => Task1())
        from t2 in Observable.Start(() => Task2())
        select new { t1, t2 };
        
    var query2 =
        from x in query1
        from t3 in Observable.Start(() => Task3())
        select new { x.t1, x.t2, t3 };
        
    var result = await query2;
}
```

Now, if the three tasks are actually `async` themselves, then it is done like this:

```
async Task Main()
{
    var query1 =
        from t1 in Observable.FromAsync(() => Task1Async())
        from t2 in Observable.FromAsync(() => Task2Async())
        select new { t1, t2 };
        
    var query2 =
        from x in query1
        from t3 in Observable.FromAsync(() => Task3Async())
        select new { x.t1, x.t2, t3 };
        
    var result = await query2;
}
```